# Jmeter File upload in Chunks

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, chunking

Hi I am testing a file upload scenario in Jmeter. The way the upload works is when i upload a file grater than 10MB, lets say i upload a 100MB file the upload is broken down into 10MB chunks. In the browser developer tools i see 5 threads each uploading 10MB chunk and the thread that completes first picks the next chunk(6th) and so on until the entire 100 MB is uploaded. I see this is not something handles in the app code and rather on the browser level. How can i simulate the same from the Jmeter Tool ?

Comment: Have you got any solution so far for the file upload in chunks? I am facing the same issue now.

Comment: There is no solution so far